# Ebean: How to filter right table in LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: ebean

I want to create a query with Ebean in like this:

```
SELECT 
    t0.book_id, t0.name, t1.accno
FROM
    books t0
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    external_refs t1 ON t0.book_id = t1.book_id AND t1.type = "doi"
WHERE
    t0.book_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The Entity "Book" contains the one-to-many relationship

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName = "book_id")
public List<ExternalRef> externalRefs;
```

This is how I create the query:

```
List<Integer> bookIds;
Query<Book> query = Ebean.createQuery(Book.class).where(Expr.in("book_id", bookIds));
```

How can I add the part `AND t1.type = "doi"` to this query?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query cannot be improved to satisfy your requirements. But I constructed different one which returns desired results. Here is the code:

```
Query<ExternalRef> queryER = Ebean.createQuery(ExternalRef.class).where(Expr.and (Expr.eq("type", "doi"), Expr.in("book.book_id", bookIds) ));
```

So instead of Books I am querying for ExternalRefs.